# A 2D array += 1 gives me negative numbers

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, argv, memset

I have a problem in my C program; I don't know why my 2D array gives me negative numbers.

I `memset` the array :

```
memset(array , 0 , sizeof(array[0][0]) * 26 * 26);
```

And I simply read a file and when I have 2 chars between 'a' and 'z' I do a simple :

```
array[c - 'a'][d - 'a'] += 1;
```

Having

```
char c , d;
```

But when i do

```
printf("le : %d\n" , array['l' - 'a']['e' - 'a']);
```

I get:

```
le : -34
```

But it's simply impossible.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc , char * argv[])
{
    char proba[26][26];
    memset(proba , 0 , sizeof(proba[0][0]) * 26 * 26);
    FILE * fic;
    char c , d;
    fic = fopen(argv[2] , "r");
    if(fscanf(fic , "%c" , &c) != 1) return 2;
    while(!feof(fic))
    {
        if(fscanf(fic , "%c" , &d) == 1)
        {
            if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' && d >= 'a' && d <= 'z')
            {
                printf("%c%c %d - " , c , d , proba[c - 'a'][d - 'a']);
                proba[c - 'a'][d - 'a'] += 1;
            }
        }
        c = d;
    }
    fclose(fic);
    printf("\nProbability of %c%c is %f\n" , argv[1][0] , argv[1][1] , (float)proba[argv[1][0] - 'a'][argv[1][1] - 'a'] / (26 * 26));
}

// use ./main le file.txt
```

EDIT : SOLVED - A noob mistake, using 2D array char to save integers ...

Thx again StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you tried *`unsigned`* `char proba[26][26];` ? Better still, make it an `int` array.

Comment: Jeremy, I think you are experiencing overflow. char can only hold -128 to 127. When you go over 127, you "flow over" to -128. (Technically this is undefined behavior, but most computers will go to from 127 to -128). You need to use a bigger data type (like int or short). If you want to understand why this happens, you should look into how the 2's complement representation of integers works.

Comment: Also, as a style comment, you can simplify one of your lines of code. `memset(proba , 0 , sizeof(proba[0][0]) * 26 * 26);` is better stated as `memset(proba , 0 , sizeof(proba));`

Comment: OMG i only see my mistake when i read your comments. I use a 2D char array to save ints ... My bad, thank you all.

Fixed, and that's good. Thank you again ... a half hour i'm on it without seeing that i use char 2D array --'.

Thx again.

PS : I'm french sorry if you don't understand all i want to say.

Comment: @Lalaland There is no undefined behavior in `char_lvalue++` on the OP's platform, because the addition is between `int` operands.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, Yes, but isn't the signed overflow always undefined behavior?

Comment: @Lalaland There is no overflow when, as `int`, you add a value from the interval -128…127 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
char proba[26][26];
```

to

```
int proba[26][26];
```

You are already using `%d` in the `printf()` format specifier, and casting to `float` later on.

Comment: Yes thank you, i don't know what i was thinking about to write something like. It's so bad ... 

Thank you :D